# Categories and products in cart Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Tell me, how you can group the products in the basket to get the following:

Category 1

product 1 - $10.

product 2 - $20.

Category 2

product 1 - $10.

product 2 - $20.

Please note that I have created a simple product and I do not need to create a variational or grouped product.

I need to show categories and their products.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage it by creating `Categories` in `Product categories` which helps you to differentiate Products.

Comment: I have product categories, but I can not group products into categories in the cart. The maximum I can do is:
Category 1

product 1 - $10.

Category 1

product 2 - $20.